# Make Eureka DateTimeInlineRow value show in textLabel rather than detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

So I'm trying to customize the `DateTimeInlineRow` from Eureka library to show the selected date in title position rather than detail position. To replace the 'placeholder' "Date" shown in the following picture:
[image]

I tried a lot of approaches with no success, this is my last attempt:

```
        <<< DateTimeInlineRow() { row in
            row.tag = "date"
            }.cellSetup { cell, row in
                row.title = "Date"
            }.cellUpdate { cell , row in
                if let date = row.value {
                    row.title = DateFormatter().string(from: date)
                }
                cell.textLabel?.textColor = row.title == "Date" ? .gray : .black
            }
```

Comment: You need to show way more code.  We have no idea what any of those functions does.

Comment: @creeperspeak I updated my question to add some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the `cell.textLabel?.text` to make your date string the title

```
    <<< DateTimeInlineRow() { row in
        row.tag = "date"
        }.cellSetup { cell, row in
            row.title = "Date"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        }.cellUpdate { cell , row in
            if let date = row.value {
                cell.textLabel?.text = row.dateFormatter?.string(from: date)
            }
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = row.title == "Date" ? .gray : .black
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    }
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]